Google Sheets formula that will take the first URL in a list
Currently I have column that has a list of URLs which are separated by |, I want to write a formula that will extract the first URL in the list. As you can see in the image example with the outcome of the formula in First URL.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T132O7gF00Cewpj-X9K9UNMMafROU8MyHYNUaBGGJ9A/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be massively appreciated

use:
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, "|")),,1)


change 1 to 2 for 2nd etc.


You may try:
=+split(A2,"|")


